# AppEngine Standard Python 3.7 does not provide error message with 500 response

Tags: google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

I'm creating an AppEngine application with python3.7 standard environment. The application works ok locally, but when uploaded it throws a 500 error in the browser it shows:

```
"Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application."
```

Debugging is not enabled for python3.7 (it tells me that when viewing the debugger). And the log entries don't have the hint of an error message within them against the 500 response.

How do I proceed to debug and understand what's happening to the application?

I should note that I'm attempting to use a Selenium webdriver to run headless chrome and I'm not 100% sure this is compatible with this environment, I was just trying to give it a go.

**Adding in log as suggested**

```
https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer?project={project-id}&resource=gae_app%2Fmodule_id%2Fdefault%2Fversion_id%2F20180916t193009&minLogLevel=0&expandAll=false&timestamp=2018-09-17T18%3A18%3A21.295000000Z&customFacets&limitCustomFacetWidth=true&interval=PT1H&scrollTimestamp=2018-09-17T18%3A16%3A59.235127000Z&advancedFilter=resource.type%3D%22gae_app%22%0Aresource.labels.zone%3D%22us-west2-3%22%0Aresource.labels.project_id%3D%22{project-id}%22%0Aresource.labels.version_id%3D%2220180916t193009%22%0Aresource.labels.module_id%3D%22default%22%0Atimestamp%3D%222018-09-17T18%3A16%3A57.883459000Z%22%0AinsertId%3D%225b9fef9e0005ebc57890705d%22&dateRangeUnbound=both

{
 httpRequest: {
  status:  500   
 }
 insertId:  "5b9fef9e0005ebc57890705d"  
 labels: {
  clone_id:  "00c61b117c38b726d0ba73ce89f222fe10b9b189fae907de84b949ab7a3b88ec4bdc4484"   
 }
 logName:  "projects/{project-id}/logs/appengine.googleapis.com%2Frequest_log"  
 operation: {
  first:  true   
  id:  "5b9fef9900ff0d7b03fbff00a7c100016d7e7370656e642d6d6f6e69746f720001323031383039313674313933303039000100"   
  last:  true   
  producer:  "appengine.googleapis.com/request_id"   
 }
 protoPayload: {
  @type:  "type.googleapis.com/google.appengine.logging.v1.RequestLog"   
  appEngineRelease:  "1.9.64"   
  appId:  "m~{project-id}"   
  cost:  4.7272999999999996e-8   
  endTime:  "2018-09-17T18:17:02.387819Z"   
  finished:  true   
  first:  true   
  host:  "{project-id}.appspot.com"   
  httpVersion:  "HTTP/1.1"   
  instanceId:  "00c61b117c38b726d0ba73ce89f222fe10b9b189fae907de84b949ab7a3b88ec4bdc4484"   
  instanceIndex:  -1   
  ip:  "80.195.185.178"   
  latency:  "4.504360s"   
  line: [
   0: {
    logMessage:  "This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. This request may thus take longer and use more CPU than a typical request for your application."     
    severity:  "INFO"     
    time:  "2018-09-17T18:17:02.387649Z"     
   }
  ]
  megaCycles:  "6127"   
  method:  "GET"   
  requestId:  "5b9fef9900ff0d7b03fbff00a7c100016d7e7370656e642d6d6f6e69746f720001323031383039313674313933303039000100"   
  resource:  "/"   
  responseSize:  "423"   
  startTime:  "2018-09-17T18:16:57.883459Z"   
  status:  500   
  traceId:  "37cee4aaaa0b14fbaa6d57b7842527dc"   
  traceSampled:  true   
  urlMapEntry:  "auto"   
  userAgent:  "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36"   
  versionId:  "20180916t193009"   
  wasLoadingRequest:  true   
 }
 receiveTimestamp:  "2018-09-17T18:17:02.563417716Z"  
 resource: {
  labels: {
   module_id:  "default"    
   project_id:  "{project-id}"    
   version_id:  "20180916t193009"    
   zone:  "us-west2-3"    
  }
  type:  "gae_app"   
 }
 severity:  "INFO"  
 timestamp:  "2018-09-17T18:16:57.883459Z"  
 trace:  "projects/{project-id}/traces/37cee4aaaa0b14fbaa6d57b7842527dc"  
 traceSampled:  true  
}
```

Comment: You can view your [logs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/overview) and check for the same time-frame this request was happening. If you can post the relevant log entities here, you'd get a solution with a better chance.

Comment: @Yurci thanks for the suggestion. I've followed your advice.

Comment: As you've mentioned, your logs don't imply lot about this issue. At this point, I suggest to implement your custom [logging](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) which also will output to [Stadriver Logging](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/writing-application-logs). The best thing would be detecting which part of the code causing this error.

Comment: Thanks @Yurci - this inspired me to insert a simple try/catch block which did the trick. Sadly for me it doesn't seem possible to use headless chrome in this environment just yet.

Comment: You can run headless chrome using [Node.js 8](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/introducing-headless-chrome-support-in-cloud-functions-and-app-engine).

Comment: @Yurci thanks for the pointer. Although I know a fair amount of javascript, I've never node.js before. Is there any quick start guide that you can point to that would help me assess how difficult it would be to pick up?

Comment: Yes, you can refer to this [document](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/using-headless-chrome-with-puppeteer)

Comment: @Yurci Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

In order to debug this further I inserted a try/catch block like so:

try:
   {application code}
except Exception as e:
   return str(e)

This lands the top level error message in the browser when the application fails.